# DualBoot 32Win & 64Mac from Live USB +Persistance

Tags: 64-bit, live-usb, mac, 32-bit, windows-xp

So I have a 32 bit Live USB with persistance that I use to write code, cause that's just how I roll. I can boot it onto my school computers(32 bit Win) no problem, but obviously not my Mac (2007 iMac, 64 Bit). Currently I use VMWare Fusion 6 Pro and a Plop Linux image to use the usb at home, but I can only get 900mb of ram for my VM. I was hoping to make a Live USB that can boot 32 bit and 64 bit for mac, with a shared persistance file, this way I can use my computer's full 2GB. Also, I'm not allowed edit any part of this Mac.

Do Not reply telling me it's impossible. Please only solutions.

Thank you, and have a unicorntastic day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution, but not really. I finally got my hands on some cd's and burned plop iso, then used that to boot usb.